# Show array get item variable

Tags: javascript

[image]

Can I show the array item in the picture by using a variable?

```
const myArray = ["badges","events"]

myArray.foreach(item=>{
 console.log(user.roleAuth.item);
})
```

Comment: use user.roleAuth[item]

Comment: also `forEach` not `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :
const myArray = ["badges","events"]

```
myArray.forEach(item=>{
 console.log(user.roleAuth[item]);
})
```

that already mentioned in comments